# nginx unknown directive "auth_jwt"

Tags: nginx, jwt

I want set jwt auth on my nginx but I got this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "auth_jwt" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I have nginx version: nginx/1.15.8
OS: macOs Mojave v10.14.2

I couldn't find the answer on Google or other websites.

/nginx.cofnig:

```
location / { 
        auth_jwt "closed site" token=$cookie_token;
        auth_jwt_key_file conf/api_secret.jwk;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

Comment: The [ngx_http_auth_jwt_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html) seems to be part of the commercial version of Nginx.

Comment: @RichardSmith you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The original JWT module is part of Nginx Plus, but then there are many opensource free modules that do similar thing:

- https://github.com/tizpuppi/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module - supposed to be a drop-in replacement for ngx_http_auth_jwt_module from Nginx Plus (but currently became a bit outdated and lacks some features that the commercial module has), supports HS256, HS384, HS512, RS256, RS384, RS512, ES256, ES384 and ES512, can get token from `Authorization` header or from an Nginx variable, will respond with `WWW-Authenticate` header if JWT validation failed, depends on Jansson & libjwt
- https://github.com/TeslaGov/ngx-http-auth-jwt-module - supports HS256 and RS256, can get token from `Authorization` header or from a cookie with configurable name, can be configured to do 302 redirect to a login page if JWT validation failed, exposes `sub` and `emailAddress` claims in `X-UserId` and `X-Email` headers respectively, easy to build a Docker image (based on centos 7), depends on Jansson & libjwt
- https://github.com/max-lt/nginx-jwt-module - small Docker image (~16Mb) based on nginx-alpine, supports HS256, HS384, HS512, RS256, RS384, RS512, ES256, ES384 and ES512, can get token from `Authorization` header or from an Nginx variable, depends on Jansson & libjwt
- https://github.com/ch1bo/nginx-jwt - supports HS256, HS384, HS512, RS256, RS384, RS512, ES256, ES384 and ES512, not only verifies the signature but can also issue signed JWT tokens, can get token from `Authorization` header with a fallback to cookie with same name (name of the cookie is not configurable), depends on Jansson & libjwt, doesn't have documentation
- https://github.com/maxam18/nginx-ejwt-module - supports HS256 and RS256, can get token from `Authorization` header or from an Nginx variable, can extract and compare payload values with predefined values, will respond with `WWW-Authenticate` header if JWT validation failed, no external dependencies
- https://github.com/andrei-markeev/ngx_http_jwted_module - supports the modern Ed25519, can get token from `Authorization` header or from an Nginx variable, exposes JWT claims json in $jwt_claims variable, no external dependencies

Despite a rather wide variety of open source modules, the commercial one from Nginx Plus has more features than any one of these modules, and is most likely much better battle-tested and also well maintained.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the last module in this list.

Comment: Keep in mind the supported directives will be different depending on which JWT module you choose, e.g. `auth_jwt` may not be a valid directive for your selected module.  Refer to the module's documentation.