# NGINX JWT authentication validating specific JWT Claims (iss, aud etc)

Tags: nginx, jwt

Want NGINX to authenticate incoming requests based on an OAuth2 token INCLUDING validating specific token claims e.g. "aud" audience claim, "iss" issuer claim etc.

ngx_http_auth_jwt_module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html) only validates the token to ensure it's signed by an expected party and validity period.

Issue is if you're using an cloud IdP (e.g. Azure AD) the above validations are insufficient as keys used to sign tokens are shared across different customer tenancies. Therefore claims in the token need to be additionally validated including the issuer, audience etc.

How can this be done with NGINX? The following module supports claims validation however is now archived:
https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt

Answer (score 1):

**ngx_http_auth_jwt_module** exposes variables that contain claims decoded from the JWT payload, including `aud` and `iss`, which will appear in variables `$jwt_claim_aud` and `$jwt_claim_iss` correspondingly. You can read more in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html) under **Embedded Variables** section.

Having these variables, you can use them in combination with `auth_jwt_require` directive to validate the claims during access stage:

> **auth_jwt_require**
> Defines additional conditions for JWT validation. The value can contain
> text, variables, and their combination. The authentication will succeed
> only if all the values are not empty and are not equal to “0”.
>
> ```
> map $jwt_claim_iss $valid_jwt_iss {
>     "good" 1;
> }
> ...
> auth_jwt_require $valid_jwt_iss;
> ```

One more thing, while **ngx_http_auth_jwt_module** is a part of commercial distribution (and you should definitely leverage it if you have Nginx Plus already), there are also [quite a few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831921/361687) free JWT modules for Nginx written by the community. Some of them also support variables and claims validation.

Comment: Do you know if we can 'enrich'  opencensus traces with custom attributes from the JWT ? For example I want my traces from nginx to also contain client_id from  JWT.